# Read Wireshark dump file for packet times

Tags: python, datetime, struct, python-3.x

My instructions were to read the wireshark.bin data file dumped from the Wireshark program and pick out the packet times. I have no idea how to skip the header and find the first time.

```python
"""
reads the wireshark.bin data file dumped from the wireshark program 
"""
from datetime import datetime
import struct
import datetime

#file = r"V:\workspace\Python3_Homework08\src\wireshark.bin"
file = open("wireshark.bin", "rb")
idList = [ ]
with open("wireshark.bin", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = file.read(struct.calcsize("=l"))        
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        else:
            if len(bytes_read) > 3:
                idList.append(struct.unpack("=l", bytes_read)[0])

                o = struct.unpack("=l111", bytes_read)[0]
                print( datetime.date.fromtimestamp(o))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the entire file at once, and then accessing it as a list:

```
data = open("wireshark.bin", "rb").read()  # let Python automatically close file
magic = data[:4]                     # magic wireshark number (also reveals byte order)
gmt_correction = data[8:12]          # GMT offset
data = data[24:]                     # actual packets
```

Now you can loop through data in (16?) byte size chunks, looking at the appropriate offset in each chunk for the timestamp.

The magic number is `0xa1b2c3d4`, which takes four bytes, or two words.  We can determine the order (big-endian or little-endian) by examining those first four bytes by using the `struct` module:

```
magic = struct.unpack('>L', data[0:4])[0]  # before the data = data[24:] line above
if magic == 0xa1b2c3d4:
    order = '>'
elif magic == 0xd4c3b2a1:
    order = '<'
else:
    raise NotWireSharkFile()
```

Now that we have the order (and know it's a wireshark file), we can loop through the packets:

```
field0, field1, field2, field3 = \
        struct.unpack('%sllll' % order, data[:16])
payload = data[16 : 16 + field?]
data = data[16 + field?]
```

I left the names vague, since this is homework, but those `field?` names represent the information stored in the packet header which includes the timestamp and the length of the following packet data.

This code is incomplete, but hopefully will be enough to get you going.

Comment: When I try to read the entire file at once I get an error.                                                                                                                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "V:\workspace\Python3_Homework08\src\wiretimes.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = open("wireshark.bin").read()
  File "C:\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 28: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: thanks,now I can read whole file. How do I figure out the packet length? Not all the packets are the same size.

Comment: One of the fields in the header is the packet size.  Add that to the length of the header itself to skip the packet header and packet data and get to the next packet header.

Comment: [Wireshark file](http://building-smarter.com/share/wireshark.bin)That's my problem I do not understand how to break up the file into its parts and I can find any info on the web.I have never work with binary file before, the lesson that was given was very short and most of it was explaining on how to handle floats correctly.I am good with problems I see, this struct module and binary file stuff is kick my but.I understand that the file is a big-endian, but other than that I'm lost.How can I figure which fields?Is their a doc somewhere I need?The wireshark website was no help.